# Juniper MX L2 policer over-policing small frames

Tags: juniper, juniper-mx, mpls-vpn, policing, metro-ethernet

Our network is currently going through a certification, and we're seeing some odd issues with the policer.

We have 2 MX240 routers set up with MPLS/RSVP/IS-IS with a Martini-Draft l2circuit configured over these. The interfaces are configured to receive double-tagged frames; pop on ingress and push on egress. There are linux probes attached to the physical interface on each MX sending the test traffic.

The certification tests consist of 3 frame-sizes, and that the MXs police the traffic at the given value (700M here).

```
PE-1

set interfaces ae0 unit 300 encapsulation vlan-ccc
set interfaces ae0 unit 300 vlan-id 300
set interfaces ae0 unit 300 input-vlan-map pop
set interfaces ae0 unit 300 output-vlan-map push
set interfaces ae0 unit 300 layer2-policer output-policer 700m-policer

set firewall policer 700m-policer logical-interface-policer
set firewall policer 700m-policer if-exceeding bandwidth-limit 700m
set firewall policer 700m-policer if-exceeding burst-size-limit 72k
set firewall policer 700m-policer then discard

set protocols l2circuit neighbor 1.1.1.2 interface ae0.300 virtual-circuit-id 1234
set protocols l2circuit neighbor 1.1.1.2 interface ae0.300 ignore-mtu-mismatch
set protocols l2circuit neighbor 1.1.1.2 interface ae0.300 pseudowire-status-tlv
```

```
PE-2

set interfaces ae0 unit 300 encapsulation vlan-ccc
set interfaces ae0 unit 300 vlan-id 300
set interfaces ae0 unit 300 input-vlan-map pop
set interfaces ae0 unit 300 output-vlan-map push
set interfaces ae0 unit 300 layer2-policer output-policer 700m-policer
set interfaces ae0 unit 300 family ccc

set firewall policer 700m-policer logical-interface-policer
set firewall policer 700m-policer if-exceeding bandwidth-limit 700m
set firewall policer 700m-policer if-exceeding burst-size-limit 72k
set firewall policer 700m-policer then discard

set protocols l2circuit neighbor 1.1.1.1 interface ae0.300 virtual-circuit-id 1234
set protocols l2circuit neighbor 1.1.1.1 interface ae0.300 ignore-mtu-mismatch
set protocols l2circuit neighbor 1.1.1.1 interface ae0.300 pseudowire-status-tlv
```

The main issue is that the 80-byte frames are being policed over the 700M limit (i.e. too many frames are being dropped), whereas the 600-byte and 1500-byte tests are dropping the correct amount.

Can anyone point me as to why more of the 80-byte frames and the larger frames aren't, and how I can fix this?

Thanks in advance!

**EDIT 1**

The testing mechanism is that the A-end sends n frames which amounts to a certain bitrate. The B-end has a min- & max-frame count, which the test should fall in between.

Comment: You aren't trying to send the same amount of L4 data with the small frames, are you? That would cause a significant amount of additional overhead and easily explain a much higher amount of frame drops. Otherwise, please add an explanation of the test cycle to your answer.

Comment: As above, the testing is being done on amount of frames being sent, not actual recv. bandwidth.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually found the answer to this today:

https://www.juniper.net/documentation/us/en/software/junos/routing-policy/topics/task/configuring-the-accounting-of-policer-overhead.html

> In order to address the MEF CE 2.0 stringent requirements to the bandwidth profile, policer-overhead adjustment is defined on a per IFL or direction granularity. The policer-overhead adjustment is in the range of -16 bytes to +16 bytes and is applied for all the policers that take into account Layer 1/ Layer 2 (L1/L2) packet length in the specified IFL or direction, including corresponding logical interface family (IFF) feature policers.

I added a -4 byte adjustment to the policer, and the tests completed successfully